# How to make 'sliding using arrow keys' work in a JSON file?

Tags: php, json, getjson, image-gallery

I created an image sliding gallery where when an user presses the left/right arrows one image slides out and the new image slides in. It worked good.

All the related images and descriptions went in my PHP file. Now I want to have some new images and I found that adding and modifying this content took me longer than it should.

So I decided to remove all the image markup and have a JSON file for the images:

Here is the code that I am using in order to retrieve the data and to inject it in the DOM

```
 $.getJSON('data.txt', function(data) {
var len = data.length, i; for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) { 
 $("#image_container").append(
 '<div class="image_frame"><img class="image" src="' + data[i].image + '" width="620px" alt="' + data[i].alt + '">
<div class="caption"></div><div class="innercaption"><p><span>' + data[i].category +
 '</span> &#124;' + data[i].title + '</p></div><div class="caption2"></div><div class="innercaption2">
<p><span>Description</span> &#124 ' + data[i].description + '</p></div></div>' );
  };
});
```

It runs at the start of document ready - But now the sliding arrows do not work, but no errors are generated.

My guess is that it would be because the content is created at the same time as the slider code. So, they can't see each other.

Is there a way to fix this (maybe run the getJSON in a way that the slider code can see it)?

Comment: Can you show us your original code? Generally the issue in doing this is that your slideshow code runs BEFORE your AJAX call actually puts any images into the page, so your slideshow thinks there isn't any images... Might want to look into the jQuery Cycle plugin, it has excellent docs &  a lot of great functionality http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: this is the page is action: http://aurelkurtula.co.uk/portfolio/ - and the box with the why arrows is where the problem is 

this is the same page when it was working without the getJSON - http://aurelkurtula.co.uk/portfolio/index1.php

the cycle plugin seems really good haven't come across that before

Comment: forgot to mention - because im a beginner, i have used a lot of files and not followed a specific structure, so (with firebug) the getJSON is located at scripts/gallery.js and the gallery animation is at scripts/anchor.js 

i sometimes find it confusing to find what im looking for due to lack of structure, so i though i'd share this